# How to use localStorage in vanillaJS

Tags: javascript

I have 2 html pages which are for a laundry services website and I have a javascript file. The first html page is called booking page where user get to book the number of clothes to be washed and it automatically calculate the total amount to be paid. Now on the second html page which is the summary page, I want the same amount on the booking page to reflect on the summary page showing the total amount and also also the buttons (plus and minus button) adding to it in the summary page.

I tried using localStorage for this project and I couldn't figure it out.

```
         Skirt(s)</p>
                  <div>
                      <p>
                        <button type="button" class="sub" data- 
       target="skirts">−</button>
                        <input type="text" value="0" 
        class="field_skirts" />
                        <button type="button" class="add" data- 
      target="skirts">+</button>
                        <p class="display_skirts" name="price" 
       max="3" min="1">&#8358; 0</p>
                    </p>
                </div>
          </div>

          <div>
              <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
          src="./img/blouse.png" /></div>
              <p class="second-booking-container-icon" 
         name="product" value="100" id="qnty_4">
                  Blouse(s)</p>
                  <div>
                        <p>
                        <button type="button" class="sub" data- 
         target="blouses">-</button>
                        <input type="text" value="0" 
           class="field_blouses" />
                        <button type="button" class="add" data- 
         target="blouses">+</button>

                        <p class="display_blouses" name="price" 
         max="3" min="1">&#8358; 0</p>
                        </p>
                  </div>
          </div>

          <div>
              <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
        src="./img/jacket.png" /></div>
              <p class="second-booking-container-icon-long" 
        name="product" value="100" id="qnty_5">Suit/Jacket(s)
              </p>
              <p>
                    <button type="button" class="sub" data- 
         target="suits">-</button>
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="field_suits" 
         />
                    <button type="button" class="add" data- 
               target="suits">+</button>

                  <p class="display_suits" name="price" max="3" 
       min="1">&#8358; 0</p>
             </p>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="third-booking-container">
          <p>Total:&#8358; <span id="totalValue"></span></p>
          <button>Set pick up date
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="second-container-button-right" 
      icon="angle-right" /></button>
        </div>
      </div>











       var subElm = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
        var addElm = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
          var totalValueElm = document.getElementById('totalValue');

     for (var i = 0; i < subElm.length; i++) {
          subElm[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
    var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' + 
        targetItem);
    var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');

    if (currentValue !== 0) {
        var incValue = currentValue - 1;
        var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
        inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
        // displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
      displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358; " + incValue * 100;
        totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) - 
        100;
    }
    });

    addElm[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
    var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' + 
        targetItem);
    var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
    var incValue = currentValue + 1;
    var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
    inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
    // displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
    displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358; " + incValue * 100;
    totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) + 100;
    });
    }






       <div class="summaryContainer">
        <div class="summaryNavBar"><p 
      className="summaryTitle">Summary</p></div>
        <div class="summaryContent">
        <p class="total" id="total">Total:</p>
       <p class="sum">&#8358;0.00</p>
        </div>

       <div class="summaryCard">
       <div class="summary-card-title">
           <div>Item</div>
          <div>Quantity</div>
       </div>
       <div class="summary-card-content">
           <div >Shirt(s)</div><div  id="
       first" class="summary-quantity"><button type="button" 
          id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
      <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
          <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>   
     </div>
           </div>
       <div class="summary-card-content">

       <div>Trouser(s)</div>
   <div class="summary-quantity" id="second">
     <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
   <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
          <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>          
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="summary-card-content" id="third">
```

I want the total calculation of price on the booking page to also appear at the summary page when I automatically click on summary page

Comment: Hey, sorry about this. I am still confused about the other like shirts, any help please?

Comment: Since that is a different issue, please ask a new question. For the benefit of future readers, it is good to confine the question to original issue. Also this way your new question gets more visibility and more people would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your booking page, store the total price in local storage using [localStorage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

`localStorage.setItem('totalPrice', JSON.stringify(totalValue));`

In your summary page, access this total price using [localStorage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

`var totalPrice = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('totalPrice'));`

Note that all the values are stored as strings, so you have to use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string back to the object or value.